# Resigned IPA with notification extension - Not recieving push notification

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, apple-push-notifications, nsnotificationcenter

Our client is resigning the IPA from ad-hoc IPA to the enterprise one. Before adding NotificationContentExtension and NotificationService extension they were able to receive push notifications. but as I give new build after resigning they are not getting notifications.is it related to adding extensions? When I am trying to download there resigned IPA I am getting error - **This app contains an app extension with an illegal bundle identifier. App extension bundle identifiers must have a prefix consisting of their containing application's bundle identifier followed by a '.'.**

Are notifications related to app extensions?

Comment: The bundle id you have assigned to your extension is incorrect - fix that.  If your base app bundle id is `com.somedomain.someapp ` then the extension must have a bundle id that extends that e.g., `com.somedomain.someapp.someextension`

Comment: Hi, Notification content extensions and notification service extension, which are used to add additional functionalities to your notifications, like showing custom contents in your notifications, are actually extensions. they are supposed to have the identifiers as com.company.product.(extension_name), where com.company.product is the bundle identifier for your app, which contains these extensions

Comment: @Paulw11 - Which IPA I made I am able to download. but when Downloading resigned IPA I am getting this error.

Comment: @AjinkyaSharma - how I can add those extensions in resigned IPA? cz it is showing error with extensions

Comment: There is only one IPA, but that IPA contains multiple executables. You need to edit the properties of the extension targets in Xcode and give them suitable bundle IDs

Comment: Adding to Paulw11's comment, you can find these extensions in the targets.

Comment: @Paulw11 - Do we have to do anything with the new provisioning profile they have resigned with after adding Notification Service extension? or they need to add in entitlement list or something while resigning for extensions explicitly?

Comment: @AjinkyaSharma - I checked there resigned IPA. IPA main target is resigned with there provisioning profile. But inside plugins in notification extensions it is still having old certificates of our account.  so how we can resign so even extension certificates get resigned.

Comment: The code signing for Extensions is same like for other targets, i guess. I think you can just ask them to make sure that if the certificates and provisioning profiles they select, for the target and extensions, before packaging the IPA are same.